# Python Socket Err: socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, sockets

Wonder if someone could help me... I get always the same error while trying to build a basic TCP web chat app...
My Server Code:

```
from socket import *

socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

ip = gethostname()
port = 4573

socket.bind((ip, port))
socket.listen(10)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = socket.accept()
    print(f"Connectoin from {address} has been established!")
    clientsocket.send(bytes('Welcome to the server!', 'utf-8'))
```

My Client Code:

```
from socket import *

socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverip = "192.168.0.24"
serverport = 4573
socket.connect((serverip,serverport))

msg = socket.recv(8192)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 8, in <module>
    socket.bind((ip, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Patricks-MacBook-Pro:WEB Chat mateostiller$ python3 server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 8, in <module>
    socket.bind((ip, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```